# How do I show database info in a map pin?

Tags: css, geolocation, mapbox, tilemill

I created a map using mapbox of team member locations per state for my company. The number of team members by state ranges from 1 - 10. The map pin (marker) symbols only go to nine.

I started to mess with Tilemill and saw a post saying it is possible to put the numbers inside of the markers, https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/advanced-map-design/ (scroll to 'Text Labels' section, it is exactly what I am trying to do).

The database column with the numbers I want is called 'marker-symbol'. Here is the code so far in the default styles.mss:

```
Map {
background-color: #b8dee6;
}

#countries {
  ::outline {
  line-color: #85c5d3;
  line-width: 2;
  line-join: round;
}
polygon-fill: #fff;
}

#features {
  marker-width:20;
  marker-fill:#f45;
  marker-line-color:#813;
  marker-allow-overlap:true;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had it right in some of the code I was testing. I just put the code in the wrong spot so it was behind the marker instead of in front of it. Here is the fix:

```
Map {
  background-color: #b8dee6;
}

#countries {
  ::outline {
    line-color: #85c5d3;
    line-width: 2;
    line-join: round;
  }
  polygon-fill: #fff;
}

#features {
  marker-width:20;
  marker-fill:#f45;
  marker-line-color:#813;
  marker-line-opacity:2;
  marker-allow-overlap:true;
  ::labels {
    text-name:"[marker-symbol]";
    text-face-name:"Arial Bold";
    text-allow-overlap:true;
    }
}
```